# Qual seria uma alternativa para a função showDialog "obsoleto"?

Tags: android, datepicker, deprecated, dialog

## Explicação:

Possuo uma aplicação mobile que utiliza o método `showDialog()` em determinado momento, para mostrar um `DatePickerDialog` e pegar a data, porém vejo que na seguinte linha:

```java
showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
```

Eu tenho o seguinte alerta:

> The method showDialog(int) from the type Activity is deprecated

Ele está obsoleto, ou seja, obsoleto.

## Código funcional obsoleto:

Declaração das variáveis:

```java
private int year;
private int month;
private int day;
static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 0;

Button btnLembrar = null;
```

Handler:

```java
View.OnClickListener handler = new View.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v) {
      if( v.getId()==3 ){
        showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
      }
    }
};
```

Atribuindo handler ao botão:

```
btnLembrar.setId(3);
btnLembrar.setOnClickListener(handler);
```

Override do evento `onCreateDialog()` e o listener:

```java
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
       return new DatePickerDialog(this, datePickerListener, year, month,day);
    }
    return null;
}

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear, int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
        util xutil=new util();
        
        year  = selectedYear;
        month = selectedMonth;
        day   = selectedDay;
        String cDta  = xutil.strZero( day, 2 ) + "/" + xutil.strZero( month+1, 2 ) + "/" + xutil.strZero( year, 2 ); 
        
        btnLembrar.setText(cDta);
    }
};
```

## Pergunta:

Qual método alternativo de realizar esta mesma operação de forma que ela não esteja obsoleta?

Comment: Use [`DialogFragment`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html)

Answer (score 1):

Na [documentação](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) do Android diz o seguinte:

> This method was deprecated in API level 13. Use the new DialogFragment class with FragmentManager instead; this is also available on older platforms through the Android compatibility package.

Onde este método não deve ser mais usado e em seu lugar deve ser utilizado `DialogFragment` juntamente com `FragmentManager`.

**Obs: Para versões antigas deve-se utilizar o package de compatibilidade Android.**

[Aki](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2012/05/using-dialogfragments.html) tem um bom exemplo de como fazer.

Há também algumas boas discussões sobre essas duas abordagens no SO-EN:

- [Esse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7977392/android-dialogfragment-vs-dialog);
- E também [esse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13765127/dialogfragment-advantages-over-alertdialog);

Comment: Tudo bem que possa ensinar como fazer ali no link se eu ler tudo e entender tudo como funciona, e talvez tranquilamente implementar isso no meu código, porém não tenho muito tempo pra ter uma chance de ler tudo aquilo e não funcionar no meu caso. Eu gostaria de uma resposta mais objetiva e autossustentável, contendo um código simples de um `Fragment` por exemplo, ou até no melhor caso um `Fragment` que use `DateTimePicker` em conjunto (que é o meu caso), porem +1 pelos links

Comment: É só respondi por que já tinha utilizado estas **referências**, que você chama de **"links"**, para implementar uma solução adequada a meu projeto, que no meu caso não envolve `DateTimePicker`. Então só posso ajudar com as **referências** ou **"links"**.